# How to map list of arbitrary name value pair from @RequestBody to java object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot mvc to build a REST service. The PUT input data are like

```
[
   {
      "PERSON":"John"
   },
   {
      "PLACE":"DC"
   },
   {
      "PERSON":"John"
   },
   {
      "PERSON":"Joe"
   },
   {
      "RANDOM NAME 011":"random string"
   },
   {
      "OTHER RANDOM NAME":"John"
   }
]
```

Notice that the name part is arbitrary, so is the value part. How to convert it using spring's automatic conversion? My code is like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cleansing", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> cleanse(@RequestBody List<CategoryItem> data) {
```

I know `@RequestBody List<CategoryItem> data` part is not right, I don't know how to write CategoryItem class to make it work. What is aright alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `Object` do you want it to be?

As the HTTP PUT payload is, your signature would work as a `List<Map<String, String>>`, but that is a bit clunky to be honest.  To retrieve values would be especially cumbersome, considering your keys are random.  Something like this would work for processing the whole set of data:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cleansing", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> cleanse(@RequestBody List<Map<String, String>> data) {
    for(final Map<String, String> map : data) {
        for(final Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + e.getKey() + " :: Value: " + e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Like I was saying...a little bit clunky.

A more flexible approach would be to use a Jackson [JsonDeserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html), along with a custom class:

```
public class MyClassDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyClass> {
    public abstract MyClass deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        //...
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using=MyClassDeserializer.class)
public class MyClass {
    //...
}
```

And then using that in your controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cleansing", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Void> cleanse(@RequestBody MyClass data) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. `List<Map<String, String>>` is good, maybe `List<List<String>>` is faster?